# How to allow ptrace in docker container

Tags: docker, apparmor

Having looked around, I found that I could use

```
docker run --privileged --rm -i -t app /bin/bash
```

This gave access too all the ptrace functions on all processes owned by any user. Unfortunately I don't want to let others have this capability. 
So I looked to apparmor, and found that I could use

```
ptrace peer=@{profile_name}
```

inside my an aparmor profile, which I then included  when running the application.

```
docker run --security-opt="apparmor:myprofile" --rm -i -t app /bin/bash
```

everything loads in fine. I then use fuser (as root) and as expected I can see processes owned by root. But I have several processes running under uucp, which gives permission denied.

So I move to bash under uucp.

```
sudo -u uucp /bin/bash
```

But using fuser or lsof does not work and returns nothing.

So how do I activate ptrace for any user when i'm active as said user inside the docker dontainer?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/#significant-syscalls-blocked-by-the-default-profile  ---> you should tried to used "--security-opt seccomp=unconfined" to disable all system call blocking by seccomp - did you tried that?

Comment: you may want to read further on docker's AppArmor profile:   https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the fix for this (https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15161) was merged to master on 2015-07-30, and was included in Docker v1.8.0 and above.  This should no longer be an issue with recent versions of Docker and the included AppArmor profiles.